# For some reason a UI button doesn't work in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a game, and I ran into a problem.
For some reason a UI button doesn't work.
I tried to do a lot, but it didn't work
Here is a video that showing what happen:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wRZNvK63XrK93PGe92lZcs8CKCYVSvts/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What is your problem? display your code

Comment: Try to use screenToGif software for creating git image of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your video link needs some kind of authentication.

So, Is there any error pops up? 
make sure you did assigned your script to your button and set the On Click() event. 
Need more info about your problem. screenshot or gif image might be ok.